# Using JSON in a Java Program

Tags: java, arrays, json

In a nutshell I'm trying to write some code so I am able to load a JSON file into my application and based on the current day/month, my program reads the correct JSON array and populates the remaining fields with those stored in the JSON array.

I have the following chunk of code:

```
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(loadJSON());

        DateFormat dayOfMonth = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
        String dayOfMonth2 = dayOfMonth.format(new Date());
        int result = Integer.parseInt(dayOfMonth2);

        DateFormat monthOfYear = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
        String monthOfYear2 = monthOfYear.format(new Date());
        int result2 = Integer.parseInt(monthOfYear2);

        try {

            if (jsonArray.getInt(0) == result && jsonArray.getInt(1) == result2 ) {
                day = jsonArray.optString(0);
                month = jsonArray.optString(1);
                one = jsonArray.optString(2);
                two = jsonArray.optString(3);
                three = jsonArray.optString(4);
                four = jsonArray.optString(5);
                five = jsonArray.optString(6);
                six = jsonArray.optString(7);
                seven = jsonArray.optString(8);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.print("Unable to find times for this day");
        }
```

So I'm storing the `dayOfMonth` in a variable based on the current date. I'm also storing `monthOfYear` in a variable based on what year of the month it is.

My JSON holds the following values:

```
["15","12","06:00","08:00","12:00","13:00","14:00","16:00","17:00"]
["16","11","06:26","08:03","12:09","13:46","14:17","16:05","17:42"]
["17","11","06:26","08:03","12:09","13:46","14:17","16:05","17:42"]
["18","11","06:26","08:03","12:09","13:46","14:17","16:05","17:42"]
```

The program loads in the first values with ease but whenever I move the position of the first JSON array, it doesn't populate the field with the values.

It seems the `if` statement is comparing only against the first array held in the .json file and if that's not the correct day/month it leaves the fields blank.

How can I modify this such that it checks every JSON array until it finds the corresponding day/month values and thereafter it stores these values in the string variables.

Load JSON:

```
public String loadJSON() {
        String json;
        try {
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("test.json");
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;
    }
```

Comment: This is not a valid JSON as whole, but just bunch of lines with separate JSON arrays

Comment: Could you please provide the code of the `loadJSON` function?

Comment: @aBnormaLz Sure. I've added it above

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Yes - that is correct however, I reference each item of the JSON array using `jsonArray.optString(0);`

This doesn't make it correct but this is how I reference it for the time being

Comment: android (and java in general) focuses heavily in XML. Unless you have an extraordinary good reason for using json, you should stick with XML. There is no reason to use 2 different markup languages in the same project, unless you really have to

Comment: I removed the `android` tag, since there's no evidence that this post is related to Android.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I think that after this `JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(loadJSON());` your jsonArray contains only the first line of the file (since the file isn't a valid json)

I think you should read the lines of the file to a `List<String>` and then call the `JSONArray` constructor for each element inside a loop (since all your lines are valid Jsons, but not the whole file)

I hope this helps. If not, i think you should provide the a bit more code, so I can run it locally